# word count or gettext after Alchemy API process with C#

Tags: c#, alchemyapi

It's a bit of long shot but I hope anyone could help me.

I'm using Alchemy API to analyze a large amount of text. The input is text files that are actually html sources without the tags. For statistical reasons I also need the text AFTER it was processed (not in its raw form) or specifically the word count. The SDK allows me to get that only through HTML or URL input. 
Does anyone have an idea?

Gil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the full text by adding the right parameters in, just like this:

```
AlchemyAPI_EntityParams entityParams = new AlchemyAPI_EntityParams();
entityParams.setOutputMode(AlchemyAPI_BaseParams.OutputMode.XML);
entityParams.setShowSourceText(true);
bool webServiceMadeIt = false;
```